# How to reload a UITableView for more data?

Tags: iphone, json, uitableview

I have UITableView, which I fill from a JSON Query.

I fill it with Private Messages and it works.

The JSON Query has the properties of "site" in which I get for every site 20 PMs.
So at the beginning I got Site=0 and got 20PMS which are loaded.

Now I wanna have the features like in the Email-app (i believe I saw it there): When you scroll down and reach the end (in my app reached the 20. PM), the application should load the next 20 and so on and so on.

Any ideas how to realize?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return ([array count] + 1);
}
```

In

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Do

```
if([indexpath row] == [array count]) {
    [self loadPMForSite:([array count]/20-1)];
}
```

In

```
- (void)loadPMForSite:(int)siteNumber
```

load the new pms and then reload the tableview data.

Not tested but supposed to work. May include typos.

Answer (score 0):

Sideswipe's answer is a good start, but you don't want to freeze the UI while you get the next twenty items.  In the last-row case, you should return a cell with "Loading..." and a UIActivityIndicator while launching a thread to actually get the data.  When that thread completes, then it signals the main thread, which can then reload the data.  As an aside, be careful not to change the size of array (in background thread) until you actually putting in the data, as you may run into a problem with the user scrolling beyond the last line if [array count] is too large.

See apple's sample:  [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

For the UIActivityIndicator:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView * loading  = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 20, 30, 30)];
[date setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[self.view addsubview:loading];
[loading startAnimating];
```